# ASP.Net MVC EditorTemplate wrong Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

So I have a `double` field called `Area`. I print it this way:

```
<div>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Area)</div>
```

My EditorTemplate for Double looks like this:

```
@{
    var attributes = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(true);
    var htmlAttributes = GAtec.AgroWeb.Basic.Ux.Web.Helpers.EditorTemplateHelper.GetAllAttributes(ViewData, attributes);
    var decimalPlaces = htmlAttributes["data-format"].ToString().Split(',');

    var value = decimalPlaces.Length > 1 ? Model.ToString("n" + decimalPlaces[1]) : Model.ToString();

    @System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(this.Html, Html.NameFor(model => model).ToString(), value, htmlAttributes);
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model)").restrictNumber();
    });
</script>
```

Nice, but why the html element comes wrong as `<input id="Area_Area" />` and the jQuery selector comes right as `$("#Area")` ?

Both `NameFor` and `IdFor` returns **"Area"** when I watch them on debbuging.

UPDATE:

My `htmlAttributes`(As @DarinDimitrov asked) returns this array:

```
["data-min": "0.0", "data-format": "0,2"]
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what the `EditorTemplateHelper.GetAllAttributes` method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(this.Html, "", value, htmlAttributes);
```

This resolved my problem. The point is, the MVC knows the model name so you don't have to say him what to print. If you do, it will concat with the model name. But why it does this, I really don't know.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of stuffing gazilions of inline scripts inside your view (one for each editor template), when you could simply append a `class="number"` to your input field and then externalize your javascript in a separate file (which is where javascript belongs) and simply use a class selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".number").restrictNumber();
});
```

Comment: Yeahm I know. Nice tip but this code isn't mine. I'll suggest that. Look my update.